# What hook is triggered when adding / updating and deleting taxonomy?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, hooks

I need to update some value in database when a taxonomy
term is added or updated or removed. What is the proper hook
to use here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [taxonomy.api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/7).

Looks like you're gonna want to take a special look at [hook_taxonomy_term_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_insert/7), hook_taxonomy_term_update, and [hook_taxonomy_term_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_delete/7).